# Extracting character from string

Tags: r, regex

I have a string lets say

```
text1 <- "John K Doe"
```

I wanted to return:

```
"John Doe"

"J K Doe"
```

I used `strsplit`, `paste` and `substr` as following:

```
paste(strsplit(text1, " ")[[1]][1], strsplit(text1, " ")[[1]][3])
[1] "John Doe"

paste(substr(text1, 1, 1), strsplit(text1, " ")[[1]][2], strsplit(text1, " ")[[1]][3])
[1] "J K Doe"
```

As you see, this return results I am expecting. But, I would want to see if there is any easy or more efficient way to do this.

Thanks and I appreciate all supports and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to using `strsplit()` is to use a regular expression with `gsub()`.  This option might be more useful if you expect to have more complex rules for extracting names and initials at some later point.

```
x <- "John K Doe"

gsub("^(\\w+) \\w (\\w+)$", "\\1 \\2", x)
[1] "John Doe"

gsub("^(\\w)\\w* (\\w) (\\w+)$", "\\1 \\2 \\3", x)
[1] "J K Doe"
```

Comment: You could get fancy and use recursion: `sub('(\\w*) (?R)?(\\w+)', '\\1\\3', "John K Doe", perl = TRUE); sub('(\\w)\\w* (?R)?(\\w+)', '\\1 \\2\\3', "John K Doe", perl = TRUE)` though I'm sure it's slower.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach which is largely similar to yours but runs `strsplit` only once

```
sapply(strsplit(text1," "), function(a) paste(a[1],a[3]))
#OR
sapply(strsplit(text1," "), function(a) paste(a[-2], collapse = " "))
#[1] "John Doe"

sapply(strsplit(text1," "), function(a) paste(substr(a[1],1,1),a[2],a[3]))
#[1] "J K Doe"
```